# Fill empty cells between two values in column with last non empty cell and next non empty cell in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, zoo, locf

I need to loop over IDs in a dataframe to fill NA values in a column by attributing empty cells evenly between the last and first filled entry outside of the NA cells.

```
ID     Value    X     Y
1          A      x     y 
1         NA      x     y 
1         NA      x     y 
1         NA      x     y 
1         NA      x     y 
1         NA      x     y 
1          B      x     y
2          C      x     y
2         NA      x     y
2         NA      x     y
2         NA      x     y
2         NA      x     y
2          D      x     y
```

Which should be filled to this:

```
ID     Value    X     Y
1          A      x     y 
1          A      x     y 
1          A      x     y 
1          B      x     y 
1          B      x     y 
1          B      x     y 
1          B      x     y
2          C      x     y
2          C      x     y
2          C      x     y
2          D      x     y
2          D      x     y
2          D      x     y
```

In case of *2n* NA values between observations, *n* is attributed to the last and *n* to the next. In case of *2n+1* values, *n* is attributed to the last and *n+1* to the next.

I know I need to use `na.locf` from the `zoo` package which works well with a large database for filling in empty values based on the last non-empty cell, along with the `fromLast` argument to perform "next observation carried backwards". I cannot however structure a loop to account for an even or odd number of NA values, and use both of these together.

Using the tidyverse package,

```
> library(tidyr)
> library(dplyr)
> df %>% dplyr::group_by(test$id) %>% fill(Value, .direction ="downup") %>% dplyr::ungroup()
```

This fills in NA values in both directions but does not account for different border values for NA cells in a group.

Comment: In the case of 1 NA between two non-NA, do you take the non-NA from previous element

Comment: No, for the next (attributing n and n+1 for the first and last half of NA values, so n=0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define interp which replaces each successive non-NA with successive integers, applies na.appro9x, rounds and replaces the  resulting integers with the original values.

```
library(zoo)

interp <- function(x) {
   x0 <- ifelse(is.na(x), NA, cumsum(!is.na(x)))
   xx <- na.approx(x0, rule = 2)
   na.omit(x)[round(xx)]
}
transform(DF, Value = interp(Value))
```

giving:

```
   ID Value X Y
1   1     A x y
2   1     A x y
3   1     A x y
4   1     B x y
5   1     B x y
6   1     B x y
7   1     B x y
8   2     C x y
9   2     C x y
10  2     C x y
11  2     D x y
12  2     D x y
13  2     D x y
```

### Note

It is assumed that the input is the following, shown in reproducible form.

```
Lines <- "ID     Value    X     Y
1          A      x     y 
1         NA      x     y 
1         NA      x     y 
1         NA      x     y 
1         NA      x     y 
1         NA      x     y 
1          B      x     y
2          C      x     y
2         NA      x     y
2         NA      x     y
2         NA      x     y
2         NA      x     y
2          D      x     y"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: An error I am facing with this is when A == B, the missing NA values would not be filled in since these are the same level.

Comment: The answer did state that it was assuming that there are no duplicates.  That was based on the example in the question  in which that was true.  Anyways I have revised it to allow them.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the simplest way is to use the function: na.locf: Last Observation Carried Forward if we are in zoo/time-series.

see: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/zoo/versions/1.8-9/topics/na.locf